# Generating 2 different results on alternative rows with a SQL query

Tags: sql

I am trying to build a SQL query to extract data in a particular format. The result needs to come from either one single query (which I am not sure how it would work) or 2 separate queries which needs to generate results on alternative rows.

To give you an example lets say there are 2 tables Vendor and Address

Vendor table has 'Vendor_ID' and 'Vendor_Name' and
Address table has 'Vendor_ID' and 'Vendor_Address'

The result needs to be like below where the numbers are rows 1 through 4.

```
1.Vendor_ID|Vendor_Name
2.Vendor_ID|Vendor_Address
3.Vendor_ID|Vendor_Name
4.Vendor_ID|Vendor_Address
```

If someone can tell me how I can do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: SSMS with MySQL? SSMS is an IDE for SQL Server. Please correct your tags, as something isn't right there.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can unpivot:

```
select vendor_id, vendor_name, 1 as ord
from t
union all
select vendor_id, vendor_address, 2
from t
order by vendor_id, ord
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and see how that works out. :)